# Embed c# image into html email

Tags: c#, image, html-email

I have a class that returns an Image:

```
public static Image GenerateVoucher(decimal voucherAmount, string voucherCode, 
DateTime expiryDate)
 {
   ...
        Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            ...various drawing on the image...
            graphics.DrawString(voucherAmount.ToString(), new Font(handleGothic.Families[0], 113), blueBrushColour, largeVoucherAmountLocation);

        }
        return img;
    }
```

and I want to embed this response into an email:

```
    public static MailMessage CreateImagedEmail(string mailTo, decimal voucherAmount, string voucherCode, DateTime expiryDate)
    {
        var mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.From = new MailAddress("fromaddress.com");
        mail.To.Add(mailTo);
        mail.Subject = "Your Email with an image inline";

        var plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
           "Your email client has detected it is unable to render html emails...",
           null, "text/plain");

        var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
           "<h1>Some HTML message </h1>" +
           "<img src=cid:voucher>",
           null, "text/html");
        var voucher = GenerateVoucher(voucherAmount, voucherCode, expiryDate);
        LinkedResource voucherImg = new LinkedResource(path);

        voucherImg.ContentId = "voucher";

        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(voucherImg);

        mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

        return mail;
    }
```

This works fine in the example above when returning the image from the file system, but when I try and add the Image from the method above the LinkedResources complains that it is not a string. I'm happy to convert it to a stream if that will work

Comment: [LinkedResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.linkedresource.aspx) has several constructors that accept a Stream ...

Comment: So is the best way to convert the image returned from the GenerateVoucher method into a stream?